# Positioning 3 divs: 2 rows and 1 column

Tags: html, css

I need to position 3 divs like in the image below: so far I got close with "float", but I was not able to achieve this result specifically.

This is my current result:

```
<head>
<style>
#div-container {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
border: 1px solid #000000; 
}
.div1 {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
.div2 {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
.div3 {
width: 100px;
height:200px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div-container">
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="div3">div3</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is what I'd like to do:

[divs image](http://s2.postimg.org/ccorm35g9/divs.jpg)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zkctxb9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it - wrap the two left hand divs in a div, and float it.

```css
#div-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
  float: left;
}
.div1 {
  width: 198px;
  height: 98px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
.div2 {
  width: 198px;
  height: 98px;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
.div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-container">
  <div id="inner">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div3">div3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:  `margin-top:-100px;` to div3. http://jsfiddle.net/xwdhppv5/